# Problem attaching WatiN to IE

Tags: testing, watin, ui-testing

I am experimenting with WatiN for our UI testing, I can get tests to work, but I can't get IE to close afterwards.

I'm trying to close IE in my class clean up code, using WatiN's example [IEStaticInstanceHelper technique](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2009/03/reusing-ie-instance-in-vs-test.html).

The problem seems to be attaching to the IE thread, which times out:

```
_instance = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.By("hwnd", _ieHwnd));
```

(_ieHwnd is the handle to IE stored when IE is first launched.)

This gives the error:

> Class Cleanup method
>   Class1.MyClassCleanup failed. Error
>   Message:
>   WatiN.Core.Exceptions.BrowserNotFoundException:
>   Could not find an IE window matching
>   constraint: Attribute 'hwnd' equals
>   '1576084'. Search expired after '30'
>   seconds.. Stack Trace:     at
>   WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.AttachToIeHelper.Find(Constraint
>   findBy, Int32 timeout, Boolean
>   waitForComplete)

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious, has anyone got any ideas about this one?
Thanks

For completeness, the static helper looks like this:

```
public class StaticBrowser
{
    private IE _instance;
    private int _ieThread;
    private string _ieHwnd;

    public IE Instance
    {
        get
        {
            var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
            if (currentThreadId != _ieThread)
            {
                _instance = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.By("hwnd", _ieHwnd));
                _ieThread = currentThreadId;
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
            _ieHwnd = _instance.hWnd.ToString();
            _ieThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
        }
    }

private int GetCurrentThreadId()
{
    return Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode();
}
    }
```

And the clean up code looks like this:

```
private static StaticBrowser _staticBrowser;

[ClassCleanup]
public static void MyClassCleanup()
{
    _staticBrowser.Instance.Close();
    _staticBrowser = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this myself by dumping mstest and using mbunit instead. I also found that I didn't need to use any of the IEStaticInstanceHelper stuff either, it just worked.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, but I'm using neither MSTest nor MbUnit.

Did anything else in your environment change that may have solved this?

Comment: I think it's down to the way the tests do their threading, this describes various settings; http://watin.sourceforge.net/apartmentstateinfo.html

The way I have it set out I navigate to the page performe actions etc. via the FixtureSetUp, then closed the browser in the FixtureTearDown. WatiN didn't play well with other configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when MSTEST executes the method with the `[ClassCleanup]` attribute, it will be run on a thread that isn't part of the [STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you run the following code it should work:

```
[ClassCleanup]
public static void MyClassCleanup()
{
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        _staticBrowser.Instance.Close();
        _staticBrowser = null;
     });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

The WatiN website briefly mentions that WatiN won't work with threads not in the STA [here](http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/) but  it isn't obvious that `[TestMethod]`'s run in the STA while methods like `[ClassCleanup]` and `[AssemblyCleanupAttribute]` do not.

Answer (score 0):

By default when IE object are destroyed, they autoclose the browser.

Your CleanUp code may try to find a browser already close, which why you have an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my problem is that the browser stays open